# Laravel 5.1 - Update list of comments after store with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

i'm doing comment system with ajax, i would like update list of comments after submit a new comment. How can i do it?

**LIST OF COMMENTS:**

frontController.php

```
public function listing()
    {
        $commenti = Comment::OrderBy('id','DESC')->get();


        return response()->json(
            $commenti->toArray()
            );
    }
```

article.blade.php

```
<table class="table">
     <thead>
         <th> all comments</th>          
     </thead>
     <tbody id="datos"></tbody>
</table>
```

commentList.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var tablaDatos = $("#datos");
        var route = "http://localhost:8000/commentList";

        $.get(route, function(res){

            $(res).each(function(key,value){
                tablaDatos.append("<tr><td>"+value.content+"</td></tr>")

               });
           });

        });
```

**STORE NEW COMMENT SYSTEM**

CommentController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->ajax()){
            $comment = new Comment();
            $comment->content = $request->input('content'); 
            $comment->user_id = $request->input('user_id'); 
            $comment->product_id = $request->input('product_id');
            $comment->article_id = $request->input('article_id');  

            $comment->save(); 

            // maybe here insert a call to update list of comments ???

            return response()->json([

                "mensaje" => "Pubblished!"
            ]);
        }
}
```

article.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'comment.store'] )!!}   

       MY INPUTS... STORE COMMENT WORK WELL. 

{!! Form::close()!!}
```

storecomment.js

```
$("#commento").click(function(){

    var dato= $("#content").val();
    var dato2= $("#user_id").val();
    var dato3= $("#article_id").val();
    var dato4= $("#product_id").val();
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/comment";
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
            content: dato, 
            user_id: dato2, 
            article_id: dato3, 
            product_id: dato4
        },

        success:function(){
            $("#msj-success").fadeIn();
        }
    });

});
```

**Routes**

```
Route::resource('comment', 'CommentController');
Route::get('commentList','FrontController@listing');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just append the new comment to the comment list when a new comment is successfully added using jQuery.

To do it, try with the following code:

```
// storecomment.js
$("#commento").click(function(){

    var dato= $("#content").val();
    var dato2= $("#user_id").val();
    var dato3= $("#article_id").val();
    var dato4= $("#product_id").val();
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/comment";
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
            content: dato, 
            user_id: dato2, 
            article_id: dato3, 
            product_id: dato4
        },

        success:function(){
            $("#msj-success").fadeIn();

            // comment added, add it to the comments list
            var tablaDatos = $("#datos");
            tablaDatos.append("<tr><td>"+dato+"</td></tr>");
        }
    });

});
```